# Set width in Ancor Constraint from UICollectionView width

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints

I need to work with the anchor constraints of a UICollectionView to build an UIView. The anchors I have inserted are all correct but I have problems with widthAncor ... I explain:

**This is My CollectionView**

```
_monthCollection = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:monthCollectionLayout];
    [self addSubview:_monthCollection];

    [_monthCollection.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor constant:65].active = YES;
    [_monthCollection.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leftAnchor constant:2].active = YES;
    [_monthCollection.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.rightAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
    [_monthCollection.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
```

**This is my UIView added**

```
UIView *cursor = [[UIView alloc] init];
    cursor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#E66163" setAlpha:.4];
    cursor.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#E66163" setAlpha:1].CGColor;
    cursor.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    cursor.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    cursor.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [_monthCollection addSubview:cursor];

    [cursor.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_monthCollection.topAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
    [cursor.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_monthCollection.leftAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
    [cursor.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:_monthCollection.frame.size.width].active = YES;
    [cursor.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_monthCollection.bottomAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
```

I need the width of my UIVIEW to be equal to _monthCollection.frame.size.width / 3

I tried in all the ways but it seems to the constraint I do not care anything .. I can not get any results ...

**So I wonder ... how do I insert my width when I use the anchor constraint?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method for creating the constraint. Instead of setting it to a constant, you want to constrain the width of your view to the width of the collection. I don't "speak" ObjC, but I believe you can easily rewrite my Swift code to objC:

```
cursor.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: _monthCollection.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.33).isActive = true
```

Comment: For now the width is correct .. I easily mistake with the constraint ... can you tell me if the other constraints are correct too?

Comment: not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but if your goal is to have a "cursor" that has the height of the collectionView and width = 1/3, and that it is positioned to the left of collectionView, then they seem right

Comment: so now how should I animate the leftAncor in didSelectItemAtIndexPath?

Comment: keep the reference to the constraint that sets the position of the cursor, and manipulate it - either change its constant to offset that would move it to the desired place, or deactivate it and again create a new one that would move it to the proper place (e.g., bind the left anchor to the left anchor of the selected cell)

Comment: You gave me a good idea, I've never tried to bind with a cell's still ... but in didSelectItemAtIndexPath how do I find the still of the next cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156377/discussion-between-abadon-and-milan-nosa).